# Splitting one line of string into different variables, from a TextFile

Tags: c#, string, split, usb, streamreader

I'm trying to parse a string from a text file, and somehow split the elements, and use them in separate variables. The string takes similar form to the following:

> TEST DISK,3819.9609375,3819.96875,FAT32

Now I'm using StreamReader to get the information from the text file, and my first thought was to use String.Split (Hence the Commas), but I couldn't find a way to get each segment into a different variable, like:

- Variable 1: TEST DISK
- Variable 2: 3819.9609375
- Variable 3: 3819.96875
- Variable 4: FAT32

My question is how can I get this string into a similar format above, if so, is there a way it can be done using String.Split()? Cheers

Comment: What do you get, when you use `Split(',')`?

Comment: You can't do it directly, meaning one step, if that's what you mean but doesn't `Split` give you an easy mechanism to do such a thing?

Comment: `Split(',')` and you will get an array of string :)

Comment: I was thinking String.Split, but I completely forgot about using an array. Totally skipped my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
string s = "TEST DISK,3819.9609375,3819.96875,FAT32";
string[] vars = s.Split(',');
```

Output:

```
vars[0] = "TEST DISK"
vars[1] = "3819.9609375"
vars[2] = "3819.96875"
vars[3] = "FAT32"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
string[] line = File.ReadAllLines("FilePath");

if (null != line && line.Length > 0)
{
    string[] values = line[0].Split(new char[',']);
    string variable1 = values[0]; //TEST DISK
    string variable2 = values[1]; //3819.9609375
}
```